# WCF and Java web service connection issue

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap, connection

I've started a team project were each team needs to create a web service which will need to expose various methods. Our team has created a WCF web service and have had no problems with the other teams consuming our services except for one team, which I'll refer to as Team B. Team B created their web service using an older version of Java (no clue what version) which doesn't support metadata exchange.

Since we are all new to WCF, and web services in general, does anyone know of a way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of metadata exchange - one is WSDL, and the other is MEX. WCF supports both. As long as you can open the web service url in a browser and see a WSDL file I'm in doubt if there is such an older java version that does not support it. MEX is a different thing but as long as you work with WSDL not interesting. You need to check with the Java team how their version supports generating clients from WSDLS (typcally there are command line tools like wsdl2java or IDE plugins) and then give them the WSDL url. It may be that there is a specific construct in the WSDL which they do not support in which case ask them for the error message.